# retrieve image from database (SQlite)

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8.1

How do I store and retrieve an image from an sqlite database in a Windows8.1 store application. I am trying to do it like this.....

store:

```
if (MainTitle.Text == "ADD WEEKLY BUDGET LIST")
                {
                   Weekly Student1 = new Weekly
                    {
                        Title = title.Text,
                        Describtion = describtion.Text,
                        Category = category.PlaceholderText,
                        Date = dateFormatter.Format(date.Date),
                        Image = (browsePic.Background).ToString(),
                        Amount = amount.Text
                    };
                    conn.Insert(Student1);
                }
```

Retrieve:

```
 dBPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "budget4");
            SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(dBPath);
            var query3 = conn.Table<Weekly>();
            var result3 = query3.ToList();
            foreach (var item in result3)
            {
                BitmapImage bit = new BitmapImage(new Uri(this.BaseUri, "Assets/images (2).jpg"));
                ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush()
                {
                    ImageSource=bit
                };


                b.Add(new WeeklyClass(item.Title, item.Amount, item.Category, item.Date, item.Describtion, brush));
                financialStuffList.Add(new FinancialStuff() { Name = item.Title, Amount = item.Amount });
            }
```

I want to browse the image and then save it in SQLite after that on retrieving it shows in border...

Comment: Do you want to save the image or the url to it?

Comment: i have saved a image in my database and now i want to show that image in a image control

Comment: It depends if you saved the Image (bytes[]) or the url to the Image.

Comment: how to save stackpanel background image source

Comment: You have to options store the bytes[] (i wouldn't suggest), or store the Uri to the Image.
The second one is splitted in two since you could have remote images or local images.
When you have local images you should store them in IsolatedStorage and then use them in your application.
Please provide more informations as From where do you take the pictures if you want to store them or just reference them.